# No stdout when attempting to run a python file with subprocess.run()

Tags: flask, python-3.6

I'm trying to run a python file from within my python script. I'm doubtful that the file is even getting run in the first place and it is not showing anything in the stdout either for me to debug.

I have tried the command 'ls' in subprocess and it worked, and was in the proper directory that the temp.py file i am trying to run is.

When i have tried to set the argument 'shell=True' it takes me into the python repl for some reason i am not sure why.

Here is the string output:

```
Terminal output: CompletedProcess(args=['python3', 'temp.py'], returncode=0, stdout=b'')
```

And here's the code used to produce it:

```
result = subprocess.run(['python3', 'temp.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)
print('Terminal output: '+str(result))
```

**EDIT**
I also just tried

```
process = Popen(['python3', 'temp.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)  
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print('Terminal output: '+str(stdout)+str(stderr))
```

No cigar:

```
Terminal output: b''b''
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an alternative that worked. I dumped all the contents of the file into the  python3 command with the '-c' augment.

```
process = Popen(['python3','-u', '-c', strCode], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

strCode being the contents of the file.